opcua python2.7 -- Writing to OPC UA server using .set_values(nodes, values)
I'd like to write multiple nodes to the OPC UA server. Therefore I use the .set_values() method of the opcua lib. I've to use the opcua lib in cause of python version 2.7.
Using the .set_values() Method doesn't work, throwing the exception:
error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
Traceback from log file given from exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):   
# I've marked the position in the code snippet below.
File "/home/runtime/scripts/WriteToOpcTest", line 44, in TestOpcMultipleWrite 
    opcUaClient.set_values(nodes5, values5)   
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opcua/client/client.py", line 672, in set_values        
    results = self.uaclient.set_attributes(nodeids, dvs, ua.AttributeIds.Value)   
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opcua/client/ua_client.py", line 674, in et_attributes
    data = self._uasocket.send_request(request)   
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opcua/client/ua_client.py", line 81, in send_request
    future = self._send_request(request, callback, timeout, message_type) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opcua/client/ua_client.py", line 72, in 
    _send_request     self._socket.write(msg)   
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opcua/common/utils.py", line 118, in write
    self.socket.sendall(data)   
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth     
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)   
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 174, in _dummy     
    raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor') error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor  

Code snippet of used methodes which leads to an error:
from opcua import Client
from opcua import ua
import Logger

opcUaClient = None

def InitializeOpcUa(opcUrl, username=None, password=None):
    global opcUaClient
    # Create a client object
    opcUaClient = Client(opcUrl)

    # Set user credentials if provided
    if username and password:
        opcUaClient.set_user(username)
        opcUaClient.set_password(password)

    try:
        # Connect to the OPC UA server
        opcUaClient.connect()

    except Exception as ex:
        FetchException(ex, "Error while connecting to OPC UA")

def DisconnectOpcUa():
    if opcUaClient is not None:
        opcUaClient.disconnect()

def TestOpcMultipleWrite():
    # Set example values
    values5 = [
        ua.DataValue(ua.Variant(10, ua.VariantType.Int)),
        ua.DataValue(ua.Variant(3.14, ua.VariantType.Float)),
        ua.DataValue(ua.Variant("Hallo Welt", ua.VariantType.String))
    ]

    # Set nodes
    nodes5 = [
        opcUaClient.get_node("ns=2;i=1001"),
        opcUaClient.get_node("ns=2;i=1002"),
        opcUaClient.get_node("ns=2;i=1003")
    ]

    # Write values as batch
    try:
        opcUaClient.set_values(nodes5, values5) # I'm line 44 which is shown in TRACEBACK
    except Exception as ex:
        FetchException(ex)

def FetchException(e):
    Logger.exception(e)

# MAIN
opcUrl = "opc.tcp://%s:%s" % ("localhost", str(4840))
InitializeOpcUa(opcUrl)

TestOpcMultipleWrite()

DisconnectOpcUa()


So, and what is your question? BTW, why do you use an obsolete Python version?

My question is, how I have to modify my code to successfully write multiple nodes to an OPC UA server.
I've to use the python version because the runtime environment (SCADA) only supports this.
